# Can I back up just one specific folder using File History on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I am interested in backing up just one specific folder using File History, let's call it "C:\Users\User\Documents\Work". This seems impossible:

1. Using the "modern" control panel, I can't add this folder to the "Back up these folders" list. The spinner appears and disappears and the folder is not added. I suspect this is because it's under the "My Documents" folder, since I can add other folders just fine.
2. Using the "old" control panel, there's no control whatsoever of what is going to be backed up. It seems to be hardcoded to all libraries, desktop, contacts, and favourites. I don't want to back up that many things.

So any way to do this?